# Selenium/Java exiting a while loop

Tags: java, selenium, while-loop, fluentlenium

I'm adding a bunch of people to a list and I want to remove them from the list later.  I've written a method that clicks on a standard X element to remove the users.  My problem is that when I get to a point where there are no more instances of the X element to click on I get an error  as follows:

"[31morg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[3]/ul/li/div/div/img"} "

But isn't that the way I'm coming out of my While loop? When the element = null and therefore the condition is false shouldn't the while loop just end and not kick out an error message?

```
public class PrivacyList extends FluentPage {

@FindBy(xpath="//div[3]/ul/li/div/div/img") 
private FluentWebElement XIcon ;


public void removeUserFromlist(){

    while(XIcon!= null){            
            System.out.println("XICON is displayed");
            XIcon.click();
            System.out.println("XICON was clicked");
        }
    System.out.println("Users Removed");
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Evaluating the Xpath address instead of the webElement solved this issue and was an easy way out of the while loop.   `while(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3]/ul/li/div/div/img")).size()!=0)`

Answer (score 2):

[PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory), using `@FindBy`, evaluates the WebElement lazily - this means first time it is used. After the first time, it is **not** evaluated again! So in your case, if it is found the first time, it will never become `null`, unless you reevaluate it every time through the loop.

You will have to use something else to exit out of your loop. Perhaps the count of the `//div[3]/ul/li` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the Xpath address instead of the webElement solved this issue and was an easy way out of the while loop.

```
while(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[3]/ul/li/div/div/img")).size()!=0)
```